# How can I change the code to make the program skip an option after user input No?

Tags: java, data-entry

I want the program to skip to "Enter another?" when N is entered after being prompted "Express?". How can I do that?
Now, when N is entered, it still prompts "Long distance?"

Below is the current batch of code. *Context: this is the data entry part of the code where user input gets added to an arraylist.*

```
String input=null;
    
    //data entry (user input + adding to arraylist)
    do {
    
        System.out.println("Enter parcel code: ");
        String pCode=kboard.next();
        
        System.out.println("Enter parcel length: ");
        double pLength=kboard.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Enter parcel width: ");
        double pWidth=kboard.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Enter parcel height: ");
        double pHeight=kboard.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.println("Enter parcel weight: ");
        double pWeight=kboard.nextDouble();
        
        Parcel parcel=new Parcel(pCode, pLength, pWidth, pHeight, pWeight);
        
        List.add(parcel);
        
        System.out.println("Express parcel? Y/N: ");
        String expressP=kboard.nextLine();
        input=kboard.next();
        
        System.out.println("Long distance parcel? Y/N: ");
        String longDist=kboard.nextLine();
        input=kboard.next();
        
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another parcel record? Y/N: ");
        input=kboard.next();
        
    }
    
    while (input.toLowerCase().equals("y"));
```

Comment: You should use an if statement

Comment: thanks, I actually used that prior to making this post but it completely skipped over the long distance prompt.

Comment: you can use if statement inside do {} segment to skip anything you want, just make a correct statement for your use case. You have an example answer from @Shivam Papat so look there, change it to be working

Answer (score 1):

Use '**if-else**' conditioning after accepting the input for '*Express Parcel*'

```
   System.out.println("Express parcel? Y/N: ");
   String expressP=kboard.nextLine();
   input=kboard.next();

   if(ip.equalsIgnoreCase("Y").  //This will execute only if previous resp is Yes
  { 
       System.out.println("Long distance parcel? Y/N: ");
       String longDist=kboard.nextLine();
      input=kboard.next();
  }

  System.out.println("Do you want to enter another parcel record? Y/N: ");
  input=kboard.next();
```

This way if user enter N or n it'll ask for next iteration skipping the code for Parcel distance.

Comment: thanks! however, it also skips "Do you want to enter another parcel record?" How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code :

```
  String input=null;

    //data entry (user input + adding to arraylist)
    do {

        System.out.println("Enter parcel code: ");
        String pCode=kboard.next();

        System.out.println("Enter parcel length: ");
        double pLength=kboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter parcel width: ");
        double pWidth=kboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter parcel height: ");
        double pHeight=kboard.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("Enter parcel weight: ");
        double pWeight=kboard.nextDouble();

        /*Parcel parcel=new Parcel(pCode, pLength, pWidth, pHeight, pWeight);

        List.add(parcel);*/

        System.out.println("Express parcel? Y/N: ");
        String expressP=kboard.next();
        if (expressP.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {

            System.out.println("Long distance parcel? Y/N: ");
            String longDist = kboard.nextLine();
            input = kboard.next();
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter another parcel record? Y/N: ");
        input=kboard.next();

    }

    while (input.toLowerCase().equals("y"));
```

you need to add an extra if to check the user has entered Y or not

Comment: hey thanks! however it skipped the long distance prompt when Y is entered

Comment: @dianeshiki maybe you are entering Y in a lowercase. I have edited by answer to handle  case in the code just change `equals` to `equalsIgnoreCase` in the if statement

Comment: @dianeshiki I have edited the answer try the answer again